# Installing JDK vs Portable JDK

Tags: java

As I know, there are two ways to use JDK in windows:

1. Download JDK installation file and install.
2. Download JDK binary.

What's the difference between them?

Comment: 1) has an installation program. 2) doesn't.  That's about it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey benefit of one over the other?

Comment: @dreamer Use 1) if you want to use the installation program.  Use 2) if you don't.  I assume you know what an installation program is.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yeah, thanks. i wanted to know if there were any other benefits other than setting/exporting `PATH` variables :)

Comment: @dreamer no, just different packaging.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The key work may be the "installation program". There is anyway to use binary JDK to run an installation program?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Pros:** Simple and easy, all of a sudden everything works. **Cons:** Everything now uses the new version - which may not be the desired effect.
2. **Pros:** You can put it anywhere you like and make sure it is only accessible by code you expect. **Cons:** More work involved - usually requires manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to unpack, set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables manually. This all is done for you.
2. You should set environment variables below manually, but you may have more than one installation of one major build (different build, for example). Also, you may put it in any place you want it to be in.